# How do Django in VIsual Studio use South migrate apps?

Tags: django, visual-studio-2013, django-south

I am new to Django and start using Visual Studio for help. I have included South package and listed it in my settings.py.

But I can only use Django shell instead of $python in the Visual Studio environment.

How do I migrate these apps/packages? Or how do I use "manage.py migrate" command in Django shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, I recommend you [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) or (if you can buy) [the wonderful PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), Visual Studio is just not for django.

to run `manage.py migrate`, just `cd` to your project folder where `manage.py` is in, and type:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

if you have installed south just now, then you need to do `sync` first, i guess.

```
python manage syncdb
```

hope this helps.